# Installing Cloudera VM in Windows 32 which supports 64 bit archiecture

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have a 32 bit Windows Operating System. But my system supports 64 bit architecture,i could say that because when i downloaded and ran VMWare Processor Check for 64 bit compatibility tool from the VMware website it shows 'This host is capable of running a 64-bit guest Operating System under this VMWare product'. So with this 64 bit architecture would i be able to install and use Cloudera VM and then hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you can go ahead and use 64 bit without any issues and hadoop will be up and running. However, you can always go back and download 32 bit and import in your VMWare and have both 64 bit and 32 bit imported. If in case you get in to any issues with 64 bit, then you can stop using it and run 32 bit.

If cloudera is not supporting 32 bit, then check with hortonworks VM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But cloudera doesn't provide the package for 32 bit system. Heard cloudera provides the best hadoop package, so other than that from which distributor(the next best) i can get the package?